# How can I fix "no data in sublime-keymap" error in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, code-editor

Whenever I try to open Sublime Text 3 this error pops up and the program never starts:

> Error Trying to parse file: No data in
> Packages\User\Default(Windows).sublime-keymap:1:1

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-keymap`. Open the file with some text editor (say Notepad++) Then enter `[]` into the file. I'm guessing it got created with no contents (which is causing the error). If there are entries there, please post the contents. Though you may be able to just wrap it in square braces.

Comment: ,First off thank you sir for trying to help me.The file was empty and I did what you asked me, but now I don't get the error message, and the programs does not start. I click on its icon and nothing happens.

Comment: Open task manager and ensure that the process actually closed. I recall there being a bug earlier where it wasn't (I don't know if/when it was actually fixed).